# How to write dataset in xml using c#.net?

Tags: c#, mysql, xml

I want to write all my table data in xml. I have tried by following code.

```
DataSet allTables = new DataSet();
allTable = getAllDBTableData();     // allTable has 34 tables
allTables.WriteXml(XMLFilePath);    // it will write only table which have records
```

The issue is WriteXml only write table which have records. If there is no record in table, it will not write in XML.

It also doesn't write column which has NULL value. In some cases, I must set NULL value for database field like ProfilePicture.
How can I write all the table data even there is no records?

Comment: This is the way xml works -- maybe you want a different format?

Comment: @Hogan That is okay if it write doesn't write table if there is no record. How can I pass value to XML if value of column is null for specific case like Image?

Comment: You can't -- there is no way.

Comment: Write the schema so you save the entire structure : ds.WriteXml(FILENAME, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);